# How to convert IOrderedEnumerable<T> to PagedList<T> which uses OrderBy and ThenBy?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, sql-order-by, pagedlist

suppose you have a class Product, with members that are declared as nested type ProductFeature:

```
public class Product {
   public ProductFeature ProductID {get;set;}
   public ProductFeature ProductName {get;set;}
}

public class ProductFeature {
   public int FeatureID {get;set;}
   public string FeatureName {get;set;}
}
```

and somewhere you have a method to load all products as a `PagedList<Product>`:

```
var list = db.GetProductList();//returns PagedList<Product>:
```

now you want to filter and apply some `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`:

```
var sorted = model.Products.OrderBy(x => x.ProductName).ThenBy(x=>x.ProductID);
```

the result of sorted can be treated as `IEnumerable<T>` and also `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`.

the problem is when we try to convert `sorted` back to `PagedList<Product>`, or `List<Product>`.

```
base {System.SystemException}: {"At least one object must implement IComparable."}
Message: "At least one object must implement IComparable."
```

Any way to convert `sorted` as a `List` again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that `Product.ProductName` and `Product.ProductID` are instances of `ProductFeature` which does not implement `IComparable` and therefore your `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` fail when you try to enumerate over the results of `sorted`. This is clearly what the exception message is telling you.

Your second problem is that you didn't tell us what you mean by "convert" when you say "convert `sorted` back to `PagedList<Product>`, or `List<Product>`." However, I suspect whatever you mean will actually be resolved by making `ProductName` and `ProductID` instances of something that implement `IComparable`.

Comment: Nice! This is exactly the problem! I think I'm going to use for example: `x.ProductName.FeatureName` in order by

Comment: @Junior Mayhé: That would be an acceptable solution. A slightly better alternative might be to make `ProductFeature` implement `IComparable<string>` and have `CompareTo` return the result of `CompareTo` on the respective values of `FeatureName`.